# RSA Cypher VisualBasic to Java

Tags: java, vb.net, encryption, rsa

I'm having problems to encrypt some strings in Java. I need to encrypt them the same way than this VisualBasic code does:

```
 Public Function Encrypt(ByRef EncryptionKeyPair As KeyPair, ByVal PlainText As String) As String
        //Use Public Key to encrypt
        m_objRSA.FromXmlString(EncryptionKeyPair.PublicKey.Key)

        //Get Modulus Size and compare it to length of PlainText
        // If Length of PlainText > (Modulus Size - 11), then PlainText will need to be broken into segments of size (Modulus Size - 11)
        //Each of these segments will be encrypted separately
        //    and will return encrypted strings equal to the Modulus Size (with at least 11 bytes of padding)
        //When decrypting, if the EncryptedText string > Modulus size, it will be split into segments of size equal to Modulus Size
        //Each of these EncryptedText segments will be decrypted individually with the resulting PlainText segments re-assembled.

        Dim intBlockSize As Integer = GetModulusSize(EncryptionKeyPair.PublicKey.Key) - 11
        Dim strEncryptedText As String = ""

        While Len(PlainText) > 0
            If Len(PlainText) > intBlockSize Then
                strEncryptedText = strEncryptedText & EncryptBlock(Left(PlainText, intBlockSize))
                PlainText = Right(PlainText, Len(PlainText) - intBlockSize)
            Else
                strEncryptedText = strEncryptedText & EncryptBlock(PlainText)
                PlainText = ""
            End If
        End While

        Return strEncryptedText
    End Function


Private Function EncryptBlock(ByRef TheRSAProvider As RSACryptoServiceProvider, ByVal strIn As String) As String
        Return ByteArrayAsString(TheRSAProvider.Encrypt(StringAsByteArray(strIn), False))
    End Function

 Private Function GetModulusSize(ByVal intKeySize As Integer) As Integer
        //KeySize is in Bits - so divide by 8 to get # of bytes
        Return intKeySize / 8
    End Function
```

I've already searched in the internet and i haven't found anything like this.
I have the public key from the modulus and exponent and i'm doing this:

```
byte[] expBytes = Base64.decode(exponent.trim());
byte[] modBytes = Base64.decode(modulus.trim());

BigInteger modules = new BigInteger(1, modBytes);
BigInteger exponents = new BigInteger(1, expBytes);

KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");

RSAPublicKeySpec pubSpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modules, exponents);
PublicKey pubKey = factory.generatePublic(pubSpec);
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);
byte[] encrypted =cipher.doFinal(field.getBytes("UTF-16LE")); 
String string = new String(encrypted);
```

The result is not right because i'm doing nothing about the modulus size - 11. Could you please explain me how can i do that in Java?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modulus size is not the problem. The problem is more likely that you are expecting the same values to be generated. They are not, not even in the VB code or Java code by itself (run the code snippets twice!). RSA PKCS#1 v1.5 padding contains random numbers, ensuring that the encryption will always result in a different value. This is the same for OAEP padding by the way.

Note that you might want to look at OAEP mode and a hybrid cryptosystem instead of what you are doing now. Then you will be safer and you will be able to handle any size of data, although the amount of ciphertext will be larger of course.

Comment: I know that it will generate always different values. The problem is that i send the Java encrypted string to the Visual Basic web-service and it can't decrypt it. And the decryption follows that modulus size rule. I just gave the encryption example, do you need the decryption code?

Comment: Not necessarily but you should update your question as "the result is not right" lists among the worst error descriptions ever.

Comment: I think that the title and the description are clear. All I need is to implement that visual basic encryption in Java.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not seeing any other error description. I presume you can do a comparison with `field.getBytes("UTF-16LE").length` yourself? Alternatively, just catch the exception that happens if you go over the maximum size for RSA PKCS#1 v1.5 padding.